# Entity Framework Core tries to add old entry when adding new on Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship in my **EF Core** `5.0.2` code-first:

```cs
public sealed class BlipPluginDto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string BlipPluginId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<SmartContactDto> SmartContacts { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class SmartContactDto
{
    [Key]
    public int SmartContactId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BlipPluginDto> BlipPlugins { get; set; }
}
```

Relationship is configured in the DBContext(`MarketplaceDb`) as:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<BlipPluginDto>().HasMany(bp => bp.SmartContacts).WithMany(sc => sc.BlipPlugins);
```

Then I try to add a record of `SmartContactDto`(new or existing) to a existing `BlipPluginDto`:

```cs
public async Task<SmartContactDto> GetOrCreateSmartContactAsync(
    string identifier,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        await MarketplaceDb.SmartContacts
            .Include(sc => sc.BlipPlugins)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(sc => sc.Identifier == identifier, cancellationToken)
        ?? new SmartContactDto() { Identifier = identifier };

public async Task<bool> AddActivePluginAsync(
    string smartContactIdentifier,
    string blipPluginId,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var blipPlugin = await _blipPluginService.GetPluginByIdAsync(blipPluginId, cancellationToken);
    if (blipPlugin == default)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var smartContact = await GetOrCreateSmartContactAsync(smartContactIdentifier, cancellationToken);

    if (smartContact.BlipPlugins?.Any(bp => bp.BlipPluginId == blipPluginId) == true)
    {
        return false;
    }

    blipPlugin.SmartContacts.Add(smartContact);

    MarketplaceDb.Update(blipPlugin);

    await MarketplaceDb.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    return true;
}
```

The `_blipPluginService.GetPluginByIdAsync`:

```cs
public async Task<BlipPluginDto> GetPluginByIdAsync(string id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var plugin = await MarketplaceDb.BlipPlugins
        .Include(bp => bp.SmartContacts)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(bp => bp.BlipPluginId == id, cancellationToken);
    return plugin;
}
```

If the `blipPlugin` doesn't have any `smartContact` it works fine (the first insert of a `SmartContactDto`), but when the `blipPlugin` already have one `smartContact` entity is telling me that I'm trying to add a item with the same id on the Join table (that was created by EF Core).

Assuming that I'm trying to add a `SmartContactDto` with `SmartContactId = 68` to a `BlipPluginDto` with `BlipPluginId = "foo"` that already have one `SmartContactDto` with `SmartContactId = 12` I'm getting the following Inner Exception:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BlipPluginDtoSmartContactDto'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Marketplace.BlipPluginDtoSmartContactDto'. The duplicate key value is (foo, 12)
```

I've tried many different ways but I'm always stuck at this, even if I do the opposite (create and save a new `smartContact` then add the `blipPlugin` to the `smartContact`).

Comment: Could you post GetOrCreateSmartContactAsync(smartContactIdentifier, cancellationToken); too , pls?

Comment: Hi, GetOrCreateSmartContactAsync is the first method there, but @Neil W already gave me the right answer, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this work needs to be done within the same MarketplaceDb Context (unit of work).

I suspect that your GetOrCreateSmartContact is using a different DbContext to that where you retrieve the original Plugin in the _blipPlugInService, which you then update at the end.

Therefore, when you add the existing SmartContact that is found by GetOrCreateSmartContact it has come from a different context to that where you are performing the final

```
blipPlugin.SmartContacts.Add(smartContact);

MarketplaceDb.Update(blipPlugin);

await MarketplaceDb.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

As a result, this final context is not tracking the SmartContact you retrieved so thinks its a new one.

In summary, when perform a batch of actions such as this you must use the same instance of the DbContext for Entity Framework to do its magic.

Comment: That solved my problem like a charm! I was injecting my services and DBContext as Transient but I'm going to figure out how to inject them to work properly. Thanks